# API pagination when total number of pages is unknown

Tags: api, pagination, powerquery

How do I paginate in Power Query from an API JSON file if I do not know the total number of records that are out there, or the number of pages?

All of the blog articles I see keep referencing the API telling you what the page limit is, and the number of pages. It seems that you need these two pieces of information in order to create a pagination to occur.

I do not have that information from the initial API (number of pages, or the limit per page). I can tell that I have 1,286 individual records when I append "&total_count=true" to the end of the API URL.

Note: I am unable to share the actual API URL due to confidentiality reasons.

Comment: See if this helps you https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/   (Note that if keeping an API URL a secret is the only way the data is protected, you probably have greater issues)

Comment: Thanks @horseyride. I have seen this article before and will review it again to see if I can get more out of it this time around.